# Grid with angular-kendo-ui grid with requirejs

Tags: angularjs, path, kendo-ui, requirejs, shim

I am trying to use "kendo.grid.min" with angular and requireJs.

In the require.config I defined this:

```
paths: {
    ...
    kendouiGrid: '../bower_components/kendo-ui/js/kendo.grid.min',
    kendouiAngular: '../bower_components/angular-kendo-ui/angular-kendo'
},
shim: {
    ...
    kendouiGrid: {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'kendouiGrid'
    },
    kendouiAngular: {
        deps: ['kendouiGrid', 'angular'],
        exports: 'kendouiAngular'
    }
}
```

And in the Template I'm trying to use it:

```
<div kendo-grid k-data-source="products"
     k-columns='[
                        { "field": "name", "title": "Name"}
                    ]'>
</div>
```

The "products" exists in the scope, but even if the binding is broken, I would expect at least the headers of the grid to be shown. Nothing in shown.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Lars, thank you for your comment. I found a good example here:
https://github.com/RupertAvery/angular-kendo
thanks again.

Comment: if you solved the problem, I suggest posting it as an answer

Comment: any resolution here ?